# node.js selenium-webdriver set connection timeout

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver

I am using [selenium-webdriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/index.html) to interact with a Selenium Grid.

When the connection to the Selenium Grid times out, an exception is thrown ETIMEDOUT).

What I need is to adjust the connection timeout value to a lower one (I'm not talking about [page load and other timeouts](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver_Timeouts.html)) but I can not find how.